# how to fix PM2 error on run a npm script?

Tags: node.js, npm, deployment, pm2

When I write the command `npm run prod` the code run normally

When I write the command `pm2 start npm -- run prod` it does not work.

Error on pm2 log:

```
 :: Created by npm, please don't edit manually.
 ^
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984:16)
     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032:27)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.17.0\node_modules\pm2\lib\ProcessContainerFork.js:33:23)
     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
PM2           | App [integrator:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
```

Comment: I tried `pm2 start npm -- "run prod"` and `pm2 start npm -- run "prod"` too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with executing npm scripts via pm2 in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51356795/issue-with-executing-npm-scripts-via-pm2-in-windows)

Comment: nop. I have the same error